# How to use UIImagePickerController to edit image in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm using `UIImagePickerController` when I take photo or choose photo then show like this

[image]

but I want like this move to scale (circle instead of rectangle ) [image]

Another Problem is when we select edit button from `UIActionsheet` then how to directly open image like second snap shot and then I can easily Move and Scale.